# CODA gleman.diag, Error in chol.default(W):

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, bugs, coda

I'd like to use gelman.diag for an MCMC chain I ran in JAGS. It is very large, so I can't provide it.

The chain contains several MVN distributions, and I use a wishart prior on the precision matrix.

Just wondering what potential sources of this error might be?

Thanks you

Comment: Your question is missing a crucial detail: what error?

Comment: Sorry. "Error in chol.default(W): the leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite." I have double checked, no monitors on constant nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You may have set a monitor on a constant parameter, which will cause `chol.default` to choke.